# Where is the upload file location in cognos analytics 11?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Q1:   Where is the upload  file  location  in cognos analytics 11?

```
  I  need to know the  upload file  location to backup  files
```

Q2:  how to set  the  upload  file   size   for  a  single user ??

```
  I  know how to set  it  globally.  like this  graph
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPFUA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Cognos 11 stores uploaded files in the Content Store database, but I'm not quickly seeing where right now.  There are files in the "data files location" (see Cognos Configuration) but looking up a specific uploaded .xlsx file in the Content Store, I can't confirm that it is any of the files in the file system.  IBM would tell you you need to use the SDK to get to this content in some automated way that is not through the Cognos Anayltics UI.

I don't think there is a per-user setting for the upload limit.  The [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ag_manage.doc/t_ag_manage_file_uploads.html) makes no mention of this setting being available per user.

Comment: Yes .  You know my pain.  : )

Comment: 1.  File  disappears  in database like a mystery.
     Which Table to backup?  (My content  or  Team content)
     Not  everyone  is  a  DBA.  
     DB crash  everything is game over.
2.  Should  have  a  per-user upload file limit.  Every project  is different.  
     Some Big , some Small .
     Data Cache can be set file by file .  Why not ?
     This  is an unfriendly design  for an Admin user.

Comment: IBM should let  us  do it through the Cognos Anayltics UI  easily. Because we pay the money. And other BI system did  it.  : )

Comment: The content store is (intentionally) a black box database. You would backup/restore the whole thing, not individual tables.

Comment: Back up and Restore ALL DB will affect all user and all system. Not a good solution.

Comment: @2015evanotes: You may consider exporting areas of content using the Cognos export feature.  You can use the "Include uploaded data" option to export the content to a safe place.  You can also schedule this export job to help your backup strategy.  It would not make sense to only backup certain tables of the content store for uploaded file data because the linkage of that data to other tables that Cognos needs would be missing in a partial DB restore.

Comment: As @aTotalStranger stated, using the deployment export to create a backup of specific folders will work well.  Then that content can be imported using the same process -- even to a different folder if you choose (although I haven't done it that way).  Restoring a database backup would be done for a development Cognos environment.  So you'll need an Analytics Administrator license and a spare Cognos machine.  Either way, remind your users that recovering from their mistakes takes time and effort.  Nothing is instant or free -- and both is even less likely.

Comment: According  your answer, I'll  backup folders for VIP as you said above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Q1
It is not clear what you mean by "I  need to know the  upload file  location to backup  files"

i.
The uploaded files are stored in the content store.

If you want to back up, create a deployment.  You can also back up the CM data base itself.

ii.
If the question is, how do I recover data from an uploaded file, which may have gone missing?  You can create a report and add all the columns of the uploaded file and run as excel or CSV.  The may not be 100% fidelity of data types etc. The proper answer is, establish proper governance for the use of spreadsheets and the like so that this sort of spreadsheet risk is lessened.

iii.
By default, the default upload location is the user's my content.

You can change that.

You do this by going to manage/ customization / profile

There is a setting to set the default upload location.

Keep in mind that it is possible that a user does not have rights to upload files to a particular folder if he does not have write permissions to that folder.

Q2:
It is not possible to set a per-user upload file limit.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer.   :)    very clearly.